# Faking system date in selenium chrome driver

Tags: selenium, date, selenium-chromedriver

So I have this test that I need to run and its time based. Kinda like a discount campaign that runs between specific dates. I want to fake the system date in the browser.

The webpage checks for the system date as soon as it is loaded. So is there any way I can change the date before it loads. Right now I can inject javascript, that only mocks the date only within the function.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("var dateYouWant = 1534413600000; Date.prototype.getTime = function() { return dateYouWant; };");
```

Is it possible that I can change the date permanently or until the browser is closed?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/238426); you shouldn’t rely on the client’s system for the date, anyway, but should determine server-side if the conditions are met.

Comment: No it is not a XY problem. The system I'm testing is used across many countries but only has a server in Germany. Do you have a solution?

Comment: To be honest, that still sounds like an XY problem. If it would be at all a problem if somebody cheated, then you should not rely on the user’s system to determine the time or date. In any case, mocking is usually fine for this kind of thing; it’s what you would do for testing any other system not under your control, like a third-party service or API.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your system time using cmd with Runtime? This works in Windows.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C time " + "12:13:35");
```

For MAC/Linux you can use Bash executable.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c your_command");
```

For example, in Ubuntu I use the following to change time:

```
sudo date --set="2018-08-08 10:05:59.990"
```

Put it inside a bash script and use it in the way I have noted above.

Comment: I'm on a mac. Is there a way?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c date 0712122318");
This doesn't seem to work. even with sudo